# Probability that two items are compared

Tags: arrays, algorithm, probability, analysis

I'm attempting to solve the following problem (from Prof. Jeff Erikson's notes):

Given the algorithm below which takes in an unsorted array A and returns the k-th smallest element in the array (given that Partition does what its name implies via the standard quicksort method given the pivot returned by Random (which is assumed to return a uniformly random integer between 1 and n in linear time) and returns the new index of the pivot), we are to find the *exact* probability that this algorithm compares the i-th smallest and j-th smallest elements in the input array.

```
QuickSelect(A[1..n],k):
  r <-- Partition(A[1..n],Random(n))

  if k < r:
    return QuickSelect(A[1..r-1],k)
  else if k > r:
    return QuickSelect(A[r+1..n],k-r)
  else:
    return A[k]
```

Now, I can see that the probability of the first if statement being true is (n-k)/n, the probability of the second block being true is (k-1)/n, and the probability of executing the else statement is 1/n. I also know that (assuming i < j) the probability of i < r < j is (j-i-1)/n which guarantees that the two elements are never compared. On the other hand, if i==r or j==r, then i and j are guaranteed to be compared. The part that really trips me up is what happens if r < i or j < r, because whether or not i and j are compared depends on the value of k (whether or not we are able to recursively call QuickSelect).

Any hints and/or suggestions?

Comment: This is one of those problems where finding the approximate answer numerically by simulation would give you some insight.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Is that implying that I actually implement the algorithm and run it a few times with various inputs and it will give me an idea of what the function is supposed to be?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. As it has already been mentioned [Monte Carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) is simple solution for fast (in sense of implementation) approximation.
2. There is a way to compute exact probability using dynamic programming

Here we will assume that all elements in array are distinct and `A[i] < A[j]`.

Let us denote `P(i, j, k, n)` for probability of comparison ith and jth elements while selecting k-th in an n-elements array.

Then there is equal probability for `r` to be any of `1..n` and this probability is `1/n`. Also note that all this events are non-intersecting and their union forms all the space of events.

Let us look carefully at each possible value of `r`.

If `r = 1..i-1` then `i` and `j` fall into the same part and the probability of their comparison is `P(i-r, j-r, k-r, n-r)` if `k > r` and `0` otherwise.

If `r = i` the probability is `1`.

If `r = i+1..j-1` the probability is `0`.

If `r = j` the probability is `1` and if `r = j+1..n` the probability is `P(i, j, k, r-1)` if `k < r` and `0` otherwise.

So the full recurrent formula is `P(i, j, k, n) = 1/n * (2 + Sum for r = 1..min(r, i)-1 P(i-r, j-r, k-r, n-r) + sum for r = max(j, k)+1..n P(i, j, k, r-1))`

Finally for `n = 2` (for `i` and `j` to be different) the only possible `Ps` are `P(1, 2, 1, 2)` and `P(1, 2, 2, 2)` and both equal `1` (no matter what `r` is equal to there will be a comparison)

**Time complexity is `O(n^5)`**, **space complexity is `O(n^4)`**. Also it is possible to optimize calculations and make time complexity `O(n^4)`. Also as we only consider `A[i] < A[j]` and `i,j,k <= n` multiplicative constant is 1/8. So it would possible to compute any value for `n` up to 100 in a couple of minutes, using straight-forward algorithm described or up to 300 for optimized one.

Comment: It seems as though the best we can get for this solution is a recurrence that we can't explicitly solve without specific values, since the problem specifically asks for the _exact_ solution, do you think it's asking for the recurrence relation?

Comment: It depends on context very much. If it is maths problem then probably they expect you to find explicit formula. If it is more about programming then this algorithm allows to find **exact** value of that probability.

Comment: It's a computer science problem, so I'll assume the recurrence is enough. I can always throw it at Mathematica to see if it can find a solution to the recurrence.

Comment: On a side note, there's nothing in your spoilers that I hadn't already jotted down somewhere along the way in attempting to solve this, so you can lift the spoilers whenever you have a chance.

Comment: On a second look at the problem statement, it tells me that "the correct answer is a simple function of i, j, and k"...which leads me to believe that this recurrence is supposed to be solved, but I can't see an easy way to do that - even breaking it up into sub-cases.

Answer (score 0):

Note that two positions are only compared if one of them is the pivot. So the best way to look at this is to look at the sequence of chosen pivots.

Suppose the k-th smallest element is between i and j. Then i and j are not compared if and only if an element between them is selected as a pivot before i or j are. What is the probability that this happens?

Now suppose the k-th smallest element is after j. i and j are not compared if and only if an element between i+1 and k (excluding j) is selected as a pivot before i or j are. What is the probability that this happens?